# Azure AD authentication dialog box not popping up when site deployed to IIS

Tags: c#, .net, azure, iis, azure-active-directory

I am setting up a new website in IIS and trying to authenticate against Azure AD but no dialog box is popping up to allow me to enter my credentials.

When running my website in debug mode through Visual Studio I am prompted to enter my credentials and the config files are identical. I have .NET 4.7.2 installed on the machine where the website is deployed.

How can I get the dialog box to show up on the website deployed on IIS?

Comment: Windows authentication is on in both environments

Comment: What happens if you hit your deployed site from an icognito browser window?

Comment: @springheeledjack Can you give an example of the dialog box you are expecting?  Is it a Modern Auth experience where it redirects you to a company hosted page or is it just a dialog window that pops up?

Comment: @Rich-Lang the dialog box I am expecting prompts you to sign into your Azure account

Comment: What happens when you use a "Private" or "Incognito" browser to hit it?

Comment: Still no dialog box pops up.